# Cypher query for the .json format with Null proper

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am fairly new to neo4j and I want to write a query which reads .json format and create a graph of the nodes. Below is my query which is successful in a file where there is no null property and unsuccessful when I have null property in my json file.

Code:

```
CALL apoc.load.json("file:/graph-phase1-labelled.json") YIELD value  

UNWIND value.nodes as nodes

UNWIND nodes.properties as prop

MERGE(n1:Node{src:prop.sourceIP})
 
MERGE(n2:Node{dst:prop.destIP})  

WITH n1,n2,prop

MERGE (n1)-[:CONNECTED_TO]->(n2)

RETURN n1,n2,prop
```

Error:

```
Cannot merge the following node because of null property value for 'src': (:Node {src: null})
```

Anyone has any idea of what might solve the issue?

Answer (score 1):

Since you cannot merge on null properties, you have to filter out the rows which have nulls in them. Example:

```
CALL apoc.load.json("file:/graph-phase1-labelled.json") YIELD value

UNWIND value.nodes as nodes

UNWIND nodes.properties as prop

WHERE prop.sourceIP IS NOT NULL prop.destIP IS NOT NULL
WITH prop

MERGE(n1:Node{src:prop.sourceIP})

MERGE(n2:Node{dst:prop.destIP})

WITH n1,n2,prop

MERGE (n1)-[:CONNECTED_TO]->(n2)

RETURN n1,n2,prop
```

Comment: Thanks Luanne for you reply but it gives below error:                                      Invalid input 'WHERE': expected 
  <EOF>
  "RETURN"
  "CREATE"
  "DELETE"
  "SET"
  "REMOVE"
  "DETACH"
  "MATCH"
  "WITH"
  "UNWIND"
  "USE"
  "CALL"
  "LOAD"
  "FROM"
  "FOREACH"
  "MERGE"
  "OPTIONAL"
  "UNION" (line 4, column 1 (offset: 128))
"WHERE prop.sourceIP IS NOT NULL prop.destIP IS NOT NULL"

Comment: I have tried to use the WHERE with MATCH which obviously worked but it only returns one set of src-[relation]-dest node.                                                               CALL apoc.load.json("file:/graph-phase1-labelled.json") YIELD value
UNWIND value.nodes as nodes
UNWIND nodes.properties as prop
MATCH (n1:Node{src:prop.sourceIP}) WHERE n1.src IS NOT NULL
MATCH (n2:Node{dst:prop.destIP}) WHERE n2.dst IS NOT NULL
WITH n1,n2,prop
MERGE (n1)-[:CONNECTED_TO]->(n2)
RETURN n1,n2,prop

Comment: Oh sorry, it's probably missing a WITH...I edited the query, please try

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to solve the issue by below query:

```
call apoc.load.json("file:/graph-phase1-labelled1.json") yield value

unwind value.nodes as nodes

unwind nodes.properties as prop 

with prop where prop.sourceIP is not null

with prop where prop.destIP is not null

merge(n1:Node{src:prop.sourceIP}) 

merge(n2:Node{dest:prop.destIP}) 

with prop,n1,n2

merge (n1)-[ :connected_to]->(n2)

return n1,n2,prop
```